# Count re structure based on month/week/year

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

I have an array like this (count and date)

```js
day = [
  { count: 1, date: '2022-07-07' },
  { count: 1, date: '2022-08-14' },
  { count: 2, date: '2022-07-19' },
  { count: 4, date: '2022-07-19' },
  { count: 2, date: '2021-01-19' },
  { count: 2, date: '2021-03-02' }
]
```

now I am looking for a new array, it should be total count week/month/year base

I am expecting like this below

```js
 month = [
      { count: 7, date: '2022-07-01' },
      { count: 1, date: '2022-08-01' },
      { count: 2, date: '2021-01-01' },
      { count: 2, date: '2021-03-01' }
    ]
    year = [
      { count: 9, date: '2022-01-01' },
      { count: 4, date: '2021-01-01' },
    ]
```

Same like week bases as well

I am trying to achieve something like this

```js
let month;
for( d of day ) {
    if(condition) {
     // calculation for count adding 
     month.push(d)
   }
}
```

Comment: you tried anything ?

Comment: I think people would need more information in order to answer this. Why is '2022-07-01' count 7, for instance? Maybe I'm missing something, but seems like it'd help to add some clarity

Comment: also wouldnt an output in the format `{
  month: {
    01: 2,
    03: 2,
    07: 7,
    08: 1
  },
  year: {
    2021: 4,
    2022: 8
  }
}` more intuitive

Comment: @OliverRadini I need a new array based on month/week/year bases

Comment: @Hunter https://codeshare.io/kmXWz3 not in the format you want but you can always convert objects into arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the answer based on [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) suggestions.

I didn't implement the groupByWeek() part, but the implementation of this part should be similar to groupByMonth() and groupByYear() function in below code.

For the groupByWeek part, the tricky part is how to get the week number of the date, I think the getWeek() function from [cmgchess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess) shared codes in the above comment section would be helpful, or you can use a date library to get the week number.

```js
    let day = [
        { count: 1, date: "2022-07-07" },
        { count: 1, date: "2022-08-14" },
        { count: 2, date: "2022-07-19" },
        { count: 4, date: "2022-07-19" },
        { count: 2, date: "2021-01-19" },
        { count: 2, date: "2021-03-02" },
        { count: 5, date: "2021-07-19" },
    ];
    
    // create a map of {$year-$month-01: $count} based on the data in day array
    let groupByMonth = day.reduce((partialCount, item) => {
        let dateSplit = item.date.split("-");
        let y = dateSplit[0];
        let m = dateSplit[1];
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(partialCount, `${y}-${m}-01`)) {
            partialCount[`${y}-${m}-01`] += item.count;
        } else {
            partialCount[`${y}-${m}-01`] = item.count;
        }
        return partialCount;
    }, {});
    
    // convert the groupByMonth map into an array of object(your expected format)
    let monthList = Object.keys(groupByMonth).map(key => {
        return {
            count: groupByMonth[key],
            date: key
        };
    });
    
    // create a map of {$year-01-01: $count} based on the data in day array
    let groupByYear = day.reduce((partialCount, item) => {
        let dateSplit = item.date.split("-");
        let y = dateSplit[0];
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(partialCount, `${y}-01-01`)) {
            partialCount[`${y}-01-01`] += item.count;
        } else {
            partialCount[`${y}-01-01`] = item.count;
        }
        return partialCount;
    }, {});

    // convert the groupByMonth map into an array of object(your expected format)
    let yearList = Object.keys(groupByYear).map(key => {
        return {
            count: groupByYear[key],
            date: key
        };
    });
    
    console.log("month:", monthList);
    console.log("year:", yearList);
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't particularly helpful. A good answer should explain the algorithm and implementation, even if it's just comments in the code. It would also help if the code is posted as a runnable snippet (which would higlight that it doesn't produce the OP's required format).

Comment: Thanks both answers are correct

Answer (score 1):

I implemeted a solution that return an `object` with :

```
key => value = month / year => totalCount
```

I hope the output is okay for your, it lookes more logical to me than use only one `date` of the `month / year` to name it.
By the way I can change the output format if it is a problem or you ;)

Here is the code :

```js
const toArray = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(k => [k, obj[k]]); // transform an object to array of array [[key], [value]];

const sum = arr => arr.reduce((ps, a) => ps + a, 0); // sum an array

let day = [
    { count: 1, date: '2022-07-07' },
    { count: 1, date: '2022-08-14' },
    { count: 2, date: '2022-07-19' },
    { count: 4, date: '2022-07-19' },
    { count: 2, date: '2021-01-19' },
    { count: 2, date: '2021-03-02' }
];

let years = Object.fromEntries( // transform the result to an object 
    toArray( // transform the object to array
        day.reduce((acc, x) => { // sort the day by month / year
            // key (month or year) doesn't exist => create the key => append the element
            (acc[x.date.split('-').at(0)] = acc[x.date.split('-').at(0)] || []).push(x.count);
            return acc;
        }, {})
    ).map(arr => [arr.at(0), sum(arr.at(1))]) // sum the counts
);

let months = Object.fromEntries(toArray(day.reduce((acc, x) => {
    (acc[x.date.split('-').at(1)] = acc[x.date.split('-').at(1)] || []).push(x.count);
    return acc;
}, {})).map(arr => [arr.at(0), sum(arr.at(1))]));

console.log(months);
console.log(years);
```

Comment: Thanks both answers are correct